# Reading what is in the vsdiagnostics blob in Azure (1.7)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've enabled Diagnostics in one of my Worker roles and published it to Azure. There was a new blob container created called "vsdiagnostics" and contained within in are two binary files. I'm assuming that these files contain the output of my Trace statements, but I'm unable to open these files as I have no idea what format they are in.

I've not found anything on www.windowsazure.com about it and most of the tools they recommend are very outdated. I have installed Cerebrata's Azure Diagnostics Manager, but that isn't able to load the Trace Logs.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time when Visual Studio is used directly with your Windows Azure application, either with deployment or with troubleshooting, it creates a container in your Azure Storage and use this container to get/put data to in between your Azure instance and your Visual Studio instance. Mostly when you see container name start with VS* i.e. VSdeploy or VSDiagnostics, you can take an account that it is related with Visual Studio.

**VSdeloy** container is used when you deploy your application directly from Visual Studio. First your cspkg is transferred from desktop to this container and then to RDFE.

**VSDiagnostics** container is used to get the intellitrace data from your Azure Instance to your Visual Studio instance and when blog is downloaded to your desktop and then it is visible in VS as intellitrace  logs.

Answer (score 0):

When you opt to view Intellitrace logs, it appears that they are loaded into the vsdiagnostics blob, before being transferred to Visual Studio.